# PHP, getenv() ignores trailing space

Tags: php, environment-variables

I have a variable in the *.env* file with a trailing space (yes it is needed). The function `getenv()`, though, does not return the string with a trailing space, but trims it instead.

The variable looks like this:

```
KEY="blabla. "
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: try define as KEY='blabla. ' - use single quotes

Comment: Yeah tried that too, still trims it

Comment: A silly way: use an another character that you don't need then replace it: `KEY="blabla.%20"`  `str_replace('%20', ' ', getenv('KEY');`

Comment: Not ideal, but this will work. If you want to post it I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: PHPs getenv() actually does not trim. Something else is going on. I highly suspect you are using some framework that reads the .env file and stores the values in the environment, and this is where the trim happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement [cbaconnier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8068675/cbaconnier)'s correct answer, here's a bit more info. PHP's [`getenv()` function](http://php.net/manual/function.getenv.php) *doesn't* trim values:

```
$ FOO='bar  ' php -r 'echo getenv("FOO") . "EOL";'
bar  EOL
```

If the project (or the framework that it runs on) uses the popular [PHP dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library to load environment variables from a file, note that this library currently trims environment variable values when *loading* them from a file. A [pull request](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/pull/179) that enables configuration of this behavior was never merged.

For a safer alternative to `str_replace()`, use nested quotes around the value and then `trim()` the quotes:

```
FOO="'bar  '"
```

```
$foo = trim(getenv('FOO'), "'");
```

This approach avoids the risk of mangling the environment variable value if it contains the search string passed to `str_replace()` elsewhere besides at the end of the value.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is in fact php dotenv library that is used. I was not aware of that. This solution does seem cleaner too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in the comments, you can achieve that with a silly way by using an another character that you don't need, then replace it:

.env file:

```
KEY="blabla.%20"
```

config.php

```
$key = str_replace('%20', ' ', getenv('KEY'));
```